# Puppeteer - the tests do not perform any action

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, automated-tests, puppeteer

so, I'm using Puppeteer with Jest. After adding

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
```

My tests does not perform any actions. It doesn't matter if I'm using headless mode or let's call it "normal" mode. Anybody can help me?

*homepage.test.js*

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const HomePage = require('./page_objects/HomePage');

const homePage = new HomePage();
describe('Homepage', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(homePage.path);
    await page.waitForSelector(homePage.loginPanel);
  });
  it('Log into your account', async () => {
    await homePage.fillLoginForm();
    await expect(page).toMatchElement(homePage.productList);
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
  });
```

*HomePage.js*

```
module.exports = class HomePage {
  constructor() {
    this.path = 'https://www.saucedemo.com/index.html';
    this.loginPanel = '#login_button_container';
    this.productList = 'div[class="inventory_container"]';
    this.loginForm = {
      fields: {
        usernameInput: 'input[id="user-name"]',
        passwordInput: 'input[id="password"]',
        logInButton: 'input[class="btn_action"]',
      },
    };
  }

  async fillLoginForm() {
    await page.type(this.loginForm.fields.usernameInput, 'standard_user');
    await page.type(this.loginForm.fields.passwordInput, 'secret_sauce');
    await page.click(this.loginForm.fields.logInButton);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has two parts, one with normal `jest` and another with `jest-puppeteer`. You can skip to the `jest-puppeteer` if you want.

## Problem (with `jest`):

The `browser` and `page` inside `beforeAll` block has no relation to the `it` blocks. It also does not have any relation with the `page` inside `HomePage` class as well.

You did not mention if you were using `jest-puppeteer` or not.

## Solution:

Create block scoped variables for the describe block, and pass the page object to the modules.

### Refining the HomePage class

Consider the following `HomePage` class.

```
// HomePage.js
class HomePage {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async getScreenshot() {
    await this.page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });
  }

  async getTitle(page) {
    return page.title();
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are two ways to access to the page inside the class. Either pass inside the constructor, or use with the method directly.

The method `getScreenshot` has a `this.page`, while `getTitle` has access to a `page`.

### Refining the test

You cannot use `this` inside the jest tests due to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3628), but you can declare a variable on top of a block, then access it later.

```
describe("Example", () => {
  // define them up here inside the parent block
  let browser;
  let page;
  let homepage;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    // it has access to the browser, page and homepage
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    homepage = new HomePage(page); // <-- pass the page to HomePage here

    await page.goto("http://example.com");
    await page.waitForSelector("h1");
    return true;
  });
});
```

Now all other blocks can access to the page. According to our previous example HomePage class, we can do either of following depending on how we defined the methods.

```
it("Gets the screenshot", async () => {
    await homepage.getScreenshot(); // <-- will use this.page
  });
it("Gets the title", async () => {
    await homepage.getTitle(page); // <-- will use the page we are passing on
});
```

Finally we cleanup the tests,

```
afterAll(async () => {
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    return true;
});
```

We probably need to run the jest tests with `detectOpenHandles` for headfull mode.

```
jest . --detectOpenHandles
```

### Result:

[image]

## Problem (with `jest-puppeteer`):

`jest-puppeteer` already gives you a global browser and page object. You do not need define anything.

However if you want to use `jest-puppeteer` and `expect-puppeteer`, you have to use a custom config file.

## Solution:

Create a `jest-config.json` file and put the contents,

```
{
  "preset": "jest-puppeteer",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["expect-puppeteer"]
}
```

Now, get rid of browser and page creation code, as well as any `afterAll` hooks for `page.close` as well.

Here is a working test file,

```
class HomePage {
  async getTitle() {
    return page.$("h1");
  }
}

describe("Example", () => {
  const homepage = new HomePage();
  beforeAll(async () => {
    // it has access to a global browser, page and scoped homepage

    await page.goto("http://example.com");
    await page.waitForSelector("h1");
  });
  it("Gets the screenshot", async () => {
    const element = await homepage.getTitle();
    await expect(element).toMatch("Example");
  });
});
```

And let's run this,

```
jest . --detectOpenHandles --config jest-config.json
```

### Result:

[image]